# serializer.is_valid() failing though `required=False` - Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer like so:

```
class DataSetColumnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_target = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = dataset_models.DataSetColumn
```

Yet:

```
ipdb> columns[0]
{u'display_name': u'guid', u'name': u'guid', u'data_type': u'STRING', u'custom_target': None, u'ignore': False, u'is_identifier': False, u'order': 1}
ipdb> serializer.is_valid()
False
ipdb> serializer.errors
[{'custom_target': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}, {'custom_target': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}, {'custom_target': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}, {'custom_target': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}, {'custom_target': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}, {'custom_target': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}, {'custom_target': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}, {'custom_target': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}]
ipdb> serializer.fields['custom_target'].required
False
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note: When validation is applied to a ModelSerializer, both the
>   serializer fields, and their corresponding model fields must correctly
>   validate. If you have optional fields on your model, make sure to
>   correctly set blank=True on the model field, as well as setting
>   required=False on the serializer field.

[link to docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#modelserializer)

Comment: Gotcha. That works. I had `null=True` and was missing `blank=True`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.