# Django / Django REST Framework: serializer.is_valid() false and can't save web API query to Postgres

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

When I run from `manage.py shell` the following:

```
from accounts.views import *
c = ExtractCRMDataAPIView()
c.crm()
```

It evaluates to `Failed.` per the code in my `views.py`.

The serializer error is the following: `{'accountid': ['This field is required.']}`. Wish I had known about this functionality sooner as now I can see exactly why it is false. That being said, all entries in `accountid` in the web API have values.

I looked into the conditions where `serializer.is_valid` will be false per ([serializer.is_valid() failing though `required=False` - Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294993/serializer-is-valid-failing-though-required-false-django-rest-framework)), and my model and serializer meet the criteria of optional fields being `blank=True` and `required=False`.

Furthermore, while I know the query is successful because I can run it in its own `crm.py` and have it print in the console, this is not saving the web API query result to the database and I am not sure why.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: After finding out about `serializer.errors` I was able to find out the specific error: that `accountid field is required`. I also did a `print(serializer)` and you can see that `accountid` is in all the JSON it is pulling, so not sure what's up.

**--views.py--**

```
import requests  
import json

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK, HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from rest_framework.permissions import (
    AllowAny,
    IsAuthenticated,
    )

from .models import Accounts
from .serializers import UserLoginSerializer, ExtractCRMDataSerializer
class ExtractCRMDataAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ExtractCRMDataSerializer

    def crm(self):    
        #set these values to retrieve the oauth token
        crmorg = 'https://ORG.crm.dynamics.com' #base url for crm org  
        clientid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' #application client id  
        client_secret = 'SUPERSECRET'
        username = 'asd@asd.com' #username  
        userpassword = 'qwerty' #password
        authorizationendpoint =  'https://login.windows.net/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ/oauth2/authorize'
        tokenendpoint = 'https://login.windows.net/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ/oauth2/token' #oauth token endpoint

        #set these values to query your crm data
        crmwebapi = 'https://ORG.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2' #full path to web api endpoint  
        crmwebapiquery = '/accounts?$select=name&$orderby=name' #web api query (include leading /)

        #build the authorization token request
        tokenpost = {  
            'client_id':clientid,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'resource':crmorg,
            'oauthUrl': authorizationendpoint,
            'username':username,
            'password':userpassword,
            'grant_type':'password'
            }

        #make the token request
        tokenres = requests.post(tokenendpoint, data=tokenpost)

        #check the value of tokenres
        print(tokenres)

        #set accesstoken variable to empty string
        accesstoken = ''

        #extract the access token
        try:  
            accesstoken = tokenres.json()['access_token']
        except(KeyError):  
            #handle any missing key errors
            print('Could not get access token')

        # check point for debugging
        # print(accesstoken)

        #if we have an accesstoken
        if(accesstoken!=''):  
            #prepare the crm request headers
            crmrequestheaders = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken,
                'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
                'OData-Version': '4.0',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Prefer': 'odata.maxpagesize=500',
                'Prefer': 'odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue'
                }

            #make the crm request
            crmres = requests.get(crmwebapi+crmwebapiquery, headers=crmrequestheaders)

            try:
                #get the response json
                json = crm.json()
                serializer = ExtractCRMDataSerializer(data=json)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    print("Success.")
                    crm = serializer.save()
                    return print("Success.")
                else:
                    print("Failed.")
            except KeyError:
                #handle any missing key errors
                print('Could not parse CRM results')
```

**--serializers.py--**

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from .models import Accounts

from rest_framework.serializers import (
    CharField,
    EmailField,
    HyperlinkedIdentityField,
    ModelSerializer,
    SerializerMethodField,
    ValidationError
    )

from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings


jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

User = get_user_model()

class ExtractCRMDataSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Accounts
        fields = [
            'accountid',
            'accountnumber',
            'name',
            ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        accountid = validated_data['accountid']
        accountnumber = validated_data['accountnumber']
        name = validated_data['name']
        account_obj = Accounts(
            accountid = accountid,
            accountnumber = accountnumber,
            name = name,
            )
        account_obj.save()
        return validated_data
```

**--models.py--**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

# Model pertaining to client information that comes out of CRM
class Accounts(models.Model):
    accountid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
    accountnumber = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    webusername = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    address1_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    address1_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    address1_city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address1_stateorprovince = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    address1_postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    address1_country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    telephone1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    formerly1 = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    formerly2 = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    nbn = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    radio = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    tv = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'accounts'
```

EDIT #2:

Here is the output for `print(json)`:

```
{
    '@odata.context': 'https://org.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#accounts(accountid,accountnumber,name)', 
    'value': [{
        '@odata.etag': 'W/"17250881"', 
        'accountid': '9c512c36-a3c3-dc11',
        'accountnumber': '123', 
        'name': 'Example Studio'
    }]
}
```

As for the `print(serializer.error)`:

```
{'accountid': ['This field is required.']}
```

Also, just in case, the output for `print(serializer)` is:

```
ExtractCRMDataSerializer(data=    {
    '@odata.context': 'https://org.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#accounts(accountid,accountnumber,name)', 
    'value': [{
        '@odata.etag': 'W/"17250881"', 
        'accountid': '9c512c36-a3c3-dc11',
        'accountnumber': '123', 
        'name': 'Example Studio'
    }]
}):
accountid = CharField(max_length=255, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Accounts.objects.all())>])
accountnumber = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=5, required=False)
name = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=255, required=False)
```

Comment: please provide the serializer.errors if it doesn't validate.

Comment: Posted. Didn't know I could do that... definitely helping me debug this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to do: `json = crm.json()`. From what I see in the code snippet provided, crm is a function and it might lead to an error like: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'json'.

I think you should be trying to do is: `json = crmres.json()`.

Comment: Oh man, total oversight on my part. Was really hopeful this would be the solution, but unfortunately even after changing, I am still getting the error. I wish I could post the output `print(serializer)`, but there is way too much sensitive info to sanitize. In it you would see `accountid` is definitely in there, but it isn't "seeing" it for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you send me two informations.
1) print(json)
2) print(serializer.errors)

Comment: Hi, I have posted to the very end of my question. I ran the query with one record and redacted as needed. I only have it pulling `accountid`, `accountnumber`, `name`. The other stuff (`@odata.etag` for exmaple) just comes out with it. Also, `accountid` is always populated and is always unique... I guess this can cause `serializer.is_valid` to fail.

Comment: I see that the error is because the json being passed to the serializer is not correct. You need to change the line for the serializer to be:
`serializer = ExtractCRMDataSerializer(data=json['value'][0])`

Comment: That took care of it! Thank you so much for your help!